# Is there an ERB engine for Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, express, erb

I'm looking to use ERB templates within a Node.JS application (written in Express, if it matters). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's something very similar called EJS:

http://embeddedjs.com/

When creating an express app, just use the -e flag:

```
express MyApp -e
```